# Jacoco Crashing on Run with Gradle 3.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco

I recently updated my Android Studio to 3.1.0 and I am using Gradle 4.4.0 and ever since I have updated my IDE I have been having issues with Jacoco. I get a runtime crash, which looks like:

```
03-29 15:41:19.944 6629-6629/com.MyApp.pr.redesign.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.MyApp.pr.MyApp.app, PID: 6629
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_773e439/Offline;
        at com.MyApp.pr.eventcollector.utils.MyApp.$jacocoInit(Unknown Source:13)
        at com.MyApp.pr.eventcollector.utils.MyApp.<clinit>(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.MyApp.pr.eventcollector.utils.MyApp.setLevel(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.MyApp.pr.MyApp.MyApp.setupLogging(MyApp.java:175)
        at com.MyApp.pr.MyApp.MyApp.onCreate(MyApp.java:77)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5740)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_773e439.Offline" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.MyApp.pr.redesign.app-EGnUUyKeM4P-cZrCGsyoUQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.MyApp.pr.redesign.app-EGnUUyKeM4P-cZrCGsyoUQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.MyApp.pr.redesign.app-EGnUUyKeM4P-cZrCGsyoUQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.MyApp.pr.eventcollector.utils.MyApp.$jacocoInit(Unknown Source:13) 
        at com.MyApp.pr.eventcollector.utils.MyApp.<clinit>(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.MyApp.pr.eventcollector.utils.MyApp.setLevel(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.MyApp.pr.MyApp.MyApp.setupLogging(MyApp.java:175) 
        at com.MyApp.pr.MyApp.MyApp.onCreate(MyApp.java:77) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5740) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Here is what my Gradle files look like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
apply from: 'gradle/configurations.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/gradleLintConfig.gradle'

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {

        }

        maven {
            url "https://maven.fabric.io/public"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        // 3.0.1 (November 2017) - is a minor update to support Android Studio 3.0.1, and includes general bug fixes and performance improvements.
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

        //Here is Jacoco reference
        classpath 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.0'

        // Nebula lint is used as a lint for our Gradle scripts. It helps identify if our
        // Gradle scripts have unused dependencies for example. Also, it checks for conformance
        // to Gradle standards.
        classpath 'com.netflix.nebula:gradle-lint-plugin:9.0.0'

        //Crashlytics - Crash reporting
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
       }

    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
        targetCompatibility = "1.8"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is the app build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply from: "$project.rootDir/gradle/findbugs.gradle"
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = '0.8.0'
}
...
 buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix="-debug"
            debuggable true
            /**
             *  Code below is commented out because it causes build issue
             *  when using newer version of gradle (3.1.0)
             */

            testCoverageEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false


            }
        }
    }
...
dependencies {
...
```

}

I don't know what the issue is. I have tried to add the `.jar` files directly to the project with the same result. If anyone can help, I would be forever grateful!

Comment: can only tell, that without `testCoverageEnabled = false` local variables will be unknown in debug mode... which makes it difficult to debug. it is still the same issue with `0.8.2`.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue with gradle 4.6 and android plugin 3.1.0 when launching build from android studio / idea. However when I use gradle to build apk and deploy it with adb it works fine.

So it seems that the problem is related to IDE itself.
It does not package right jacoco version to apk.

EDIT:
I've disabled instant run and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I cant say my answer is the definitive problem because I can't see your dependencies in app build.gradle, but with this newest version of Gradle "compile" is no longer supported. This might be the root cause either in your build.gradle or the build.gradle of Jacoco.